# Class hierarchy of Shopping Cart Price Rules

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php

Class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` has an object of `salesrule/rule_collection`, and that object calls a function `validate` of class    `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Found`, what I didn't understand is how the object of `salesrule/rule_collection` is related to Found class, and if we add any other function to this class and try to access it will throw an Exception *Undefined Function*, I just want to understand whats going on behind the scenes

**UPDATE**

`Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Found` extends the class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine` but when from `process` function of the 
`Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` called it calls the `validate` function of the `Found` class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` object call to `process`

```
try {
   $validator = Mage::getModel('module/validator')
                    ->init($customer->getWebsiteId(), $customerGroupId);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   Mage::log('Exception: ' . $e . ' in ' . __CLASS__ . ' on ' . __LINE__);
}
$v  = $validator->process($quote);
```

And the `process` function of `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` which calls the `validate` function of `Found` class

```
public function process($_quote) 
{
         $quote           = $_quote;
         $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
         foreach ($this->_rules as $rule) {

            if ($rule->getIsValid() === false) {
              continue;
            }
            if ($rule->getIsValid() !== true) { 
                $rule->afterLoad();
                if (!$rule->validate($quote)) { // quote does not meet rule's conditions , //Call Found.php
                $rule->setIsValid(false);
                continue;
                }
                $rule->setIsValid(true); // passed all validations, remember to be valid
            }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

And the `validate` function of `Found` class

```
   public function validate(Varien_Object $object) 
   {
//Called form Validator.php
    $all       = $this->getAggregator() === 'all';
    $true      = (bool)$this->getValue();
    $found     = false;

    $Count =  count($object->getAllItems()); 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($object->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $found = $all ? true : false;
        foreach ($this->getConditions() as $cond) {

            $validated = $cond->validate($item); // Call to Product.php's function 'validate'

            if($validated) {
                $this->_ProductId[] = $item->getProductId();
            }

            if($i == $Count) {
                if ($all && !$validated) {
                $found = false;
                break;
                } elseif (!$all && $validated) {
                $found = true;
                break 2;
                }
            }

                }
            if($i == $Count) {
            if ($found && $true) {
                break;
            }
            }
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Now what I didn't understand is if I write any other function in `Found` class let it be `public function Foo()` and try to call it from `process` function of class `Validator` like

```
    $rule->Foo();
```

it will throw an Exception *Undefined Function*
I just want to know the reason why I can't write any function in `Found` class and call like `process`
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When calling the `$rule->validate()` you end up calling `$rule->getConditions()->validate()`. This validates every condition and a condition is an instance of the class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine` or one of it's descendants.
One of the descendants is `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Found`. Depending on the conditions you set for your rule, you may or may not end up in that class.
The module comes in play when you add a condition by selecting `Product attribute combination` when defining the rule.
See what all models mean in the method `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Combine::getNewChildSelectOptions`

```
$conditions = array_merge_recursive($conditions, array(
    //this is what you are looking for
    array('value'=>'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found', 'label'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Product attribute combination')),
    array('value'=>'salesrule/rule_condition_product_subselect', 'label'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Products subselection')),
    array('value'=>'salesrule/rule_condition_combine', 'label'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Conditions combination')),
    array('label'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Cart Attribute'), 'value'=>$attributes),
));
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot to understand how rules work, but as you said `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Found` is decedent of 'Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine' and we can call its validate function as `$rule->validate()` but I tried to write an other function in that Found class i-e  '$rule->MyCustomMethod()' it keep sending me an error **Undefined Function**. So how can I write custom method and call it through same object $rule

Comment: `$rule` is not an instance of `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Found` It is an instance of `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule`. You need to add the method on that class.

Comment: Sorry but I am bit confused, is 'validate' defined some where to be called by $rule ? because its also a function of Found class but we are calling it through $rule. Or didn't that code mean exactly ? 'array('value'=>'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found', 'label'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Product attribute combination'))' 
Thanks for the help

Comment: *Or what that code mean exactly ?